# column with a fixed number of numbers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, character, minimum

I'm trying to automate an excel work using pandas.

I have a given database with a column 'reference', this column should have 2 numbers (example: 25, 53, 45...).

I need to have all the rows in the column with two numbers but references like 1, 2, 3, 4 until 9 are only 1 number.

Is there a function I can add in order to transform the whole rows of this column to two numbers reference?

I have already tried the if-statement but it didn't give any result.

sorry for my English, I hope I made myself understood :)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

## reference# #column 2#  #column 3

1   Yellow  7474
10  brown   8220
43  white   29374
45  black   993
2   brown   9220
5   brown   2929
39  black   3683

df.set_index('reference', inplace=True)

.....

My output has to be like this :

## reference# #column 2#  #column 3

01  Yellow  7474
10  brown   8220
43  white   29374
45  black   993
02  brown   9220
05  brown   2929
39  black   3683

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately its not very clear what you are asking. As you are using Pandas, I assume your data is in CSV format. Could you share an example section of your data? It may also help to share an example of the output you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to post a data sample of what you have and what you are looking for?

To read in your excel document use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel_doc.xlsx')
```

In general, if you have a 'reference' column in pandas we would call this the 'index' column.

You can set the index by going:

```
df.set_index('reference_column',inplace=True)
```

If you are trying to add a zero in front of the numbers (less than 9) you need to turn it into a text string. You can then use zfill to 'fill' in the 0 for the numbers less than 2 digits.

```
df['column_of_numbers'].str.zfill(2)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Do I need to turn it to a text string in the excel file ? or using python ?